# tomcat mapping domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, tomcat

How to config tomcat mapping domain name?

This is what I try, but it doesn't work:

server.xml:

```
<Host name="api.example.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Alias>api.example.com</Alias>
    <Alias>www.api.example.com</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="" debug="0" privileged="true" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"    
      directory="logs"   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" 
   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
</Host>
```

I want to make my url like: www.api.example.com:8080

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not map your domain name. You need DNS for that. The name attribute in the Host element is needed just for Virtual Hosting.